# How can I get a column of value from hashmap

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I have a hashmap listview with four key and multiple value that retrieve from database. For now I can get all the value from the key of FOODID2, FOODNAME2, PRICE2, RATING2 and display via toast. But what I want is just the value from the key (FOODID2) to be display. Is it possible to do it? And correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

```
for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i=i+4)
    {   
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(FOODID2, (String) data.get(i));
        map.put(FOODNAME2, (String) data.get(i+1));
        map.put(PRICE2, (String) data.get(i+2));
        map.put(RATING2, (String) data.get(i+3));

        LIST2.add(map);

        for(Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey().equals(FOODID2))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "EXISTS "  + entry.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get entry.getKey() and just validate this 
if(entry.getKey().equls("YOUR KEY NAME"))
{
    // here u can print the toaste.
}

Comment: Still the same, I still can get value from different key

Answer (score 0):

You can loop `map.keySet()` to get all the keys, loop `map.values()` to get all the values.

Comment: Sorry for the question, what i want is all the value of the key but no the key

Comment: @user3040029 If you would like to get all the values in the map, just loop `map.values()`!!

Comment: I just want the value of FOODID2 but now all the value

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `map.get(FOODID2)`? That is, something like this...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (HashMap<String, String> map : LIST2) {
  if (sb.length() > 0) {
    sb.append(", ");
  }
  sb.append("EXISTS " + map.get(FOODID2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use`hashMap.get(key)`  to get the value of a particular key.
or in your code you can use a if statement to check for the key.